# 4:3 with documentclass{scrartcl}

Tags: xetex, presentations

I have written down a xelatex document w/ the documentclass scrartcl. It is a long document w/ many formulas & pictures. Now I have to present it shortly on a normal beamer (4:3 or 16:9 or 16:10, I can't test it).
I have tried the documentclass beamer, but I get so many error warnings, the pictures ironically go over the border of the page in the broadness now & formulas get over the border of the page.

Is there a way just to go to 4:3 w/out doing something in which a lot of commands do not work?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2):

If your documents relays on `scrartcl`, maybe you could just take the standard page size from `beamer`?

```
\documentclass[paper=128mm:96mm, landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am confused: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations#Simple_presentations :-)

Comment: I decided to use an aspect ratio of 16:9 in my example.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, but why are you confused?

Comment: I wanted to basically post the same answer that you already posted. I added the example to the wikibooks maybe two weeks ago :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Ah, thanks for explaining! Otherwise I would have been confused!